# C simple array access comparison

Tags: c, arrays, character

```
int isEmpty(char x [1000]){
    int i = 0;

    while( x[i] == " " || x[i] == "/t" || x[i] == ""){
        i++;
    }

    if (i != 999)
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The errors I recieve:

**warning: comparison between pointer and integer**

**warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior**

I realise my code reads far too much like Java, I haven't fully grapled with the C syntax yet.

Comment: you should know that `"/t"` is not the tab character, you probably mean `"\t"`

Comment: Besides of the errors that others explained already, you should have a look into the character classification functions, namely `isblank`, only available for C99, and `isspace`, available also for hereditary C.

Comment: Change the `if` and the two `return` statements to `return i != 999;`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're expressing `char` values by using string literals.  Instead of surrounding them with double quotes `"` use single quotes `'`

```
while( x[i] == ' ' || x[i] == '\t' ) {
```

Couple of other issues.

- You probably mean `\t` and not `/t`.  The former is a tab character while the latter is two characters
- Not sure what you're trying to get at with `""`.  Perhaps `\0`

Comment: ... and you should stick an `i < 1000 && ( ... )` in front of the whole list of conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are comparing with **char    constants**, you need to use single    quotes and not double quotes as:

```
x[i] == ' '
```

Double quotes are used for string constants like `"foo"`. So `"\n"` is a string literal with a single char and `'\n'` is a char constant.

Comment: And if you were to be comparing strings, the == would be comparing the address that the string starts at, not the contents of the string, which is almost certainly not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

1. Characters should be enclosed in `' '`(single quotes).
2. It's `\t` & not `/t` for the tab character.
3. Remove the case with a  blank string `""` (it's equivalent to a `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, I think

1. Should the checking continue if a `NULL (\0)` is found in `x`? I think that answer might be: **NO**.
2. It is better to separate the detection logic of empty character from the logic of empty string
3. The `(i != 999)` part is unclear. Won't it be `(i == 1000)`?
4. There are unmatched parentheses in the OP's code.

Here is my version:

```
/* return 1 when c is considered empty, 0 otherwise */
int isEmptyChar( const char c ) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
}

enum { N = 1000 };

/* return 1 when x is considered empty, 0 otherwise */
int isEmptyString( const char x[ N ] ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        if( x[ i ] == '\0' ) {
            break;      /* stop, if NUL termination is found */
        }
        if( ! isEmptyChar( x[ i ] ) ) {
            return 0;   /* early return if non-empty char is found */
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int isEmpty(const char *x)
{
  return EOF==sscanf(x,"%*s");
}
```

should also do what you want, is C89 and test whitespaces for you.